# Does Matlab command `gmres` support flexible gmres with a nonlinear preconditioner?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

About the flexible GMRES (fgmres), we know that it is a variant of right preconditioned gmres. And the robust command `gmres` in matlab as follows:

```matlab
>> help gmres
 gmres   Generalized Minimum Residual Method.
    X = gmres(A,B) attempts to solve the system of linear equations A*X = B
    for X.  The N-by-N coefficient matrix A must be square and the right
    hand side column vector B must have length N. This uses the unrestarted
    method with MIN(N,10) total iterations.

    X = gmres(AFUN,B) accepts a function handle AFUN instead of the matrix
    A. AFUN(X) accepts a vector input X and returns the matrix-vector
    product A*X. In all of the following syntaxes, you can replace A by
    AFUN.

    X = gmres(A,B,RESTART) restarts the method every RESTART iterations.
    If RESTART is N or [] then gmres uses the unrestarted method as above.

    X = gmres(A,B,RESTART,TOL) specifies the tolerance of the method.  If
    TOL is [] then gmres uses the default, 1e-6.

    X = gmres(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT) specifies the maximum number of outer
    iterations. Note: the total number of iterations is RESTART*MAXIT. If
    MAXIT is [] then gmres uses the default, MIN(N/RESTART,10). If RESTART
    is N or [] then the total number of iterations is MAXIT.

    X = gmres(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT,M) and
    X = gmres(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT,M1,M2) use preconditioner M or M=M1*M2
    and effectively solve the system inv(M)*A*X = inv(M)*B for X. If M is
    [] then a preconditioner is not applied.  M may be a function handle
    returning M\X.

    X = gmres(A,B,RESTART,TOL,MAXIT,M1,M2,X0) specifies the first initial
    guess. If X0 is [] then gmres uses the default, an all zero vector.

    [X,FLAG] = gmres(A,B,...) also returns a convergence FLAG:
     0 gmres converged to the desired tolerance TOL within MAXIT iterations.
     1 gmres iterated MAXIT times but did not converge.
     2 preconditioner M was ill-conditioned.
     3 gmres stagnated (two consecutive iterates were the same).

    [X,FLAG,RELRES] = gmres(A,B,...) also returns the relative residual
    NORM(B-A*X)/NORM(B). If FLAG is 0, then RELRES <= TOL. Note with
    preconditioners M1,M2, the residual is NORM(M2\(M1\(B-A*X))).
```

We can see that the matlab command `gmres` can support left and right preconditioned gmres. Does it support the `fgmres` with a nonlinear preconditioner? How to implement it? Thanks

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/11834/20688)

Comment: @AntonMenshov,Thanks. But I just want to know that whether MATLAB's command `gmres.m` supports `fgmres`?

Comment: Did you find an answer? It seems like there is no such support

Comment: @Coconut yes, no such a fgmres in matlab